# Does Juragedo always cause a replay?

Tags: yu-gi-oh

If I SS Juragedo during the battle step, does it always cause a replay?

> During either player's Battle Step: You can Special Summon this card
>   from your hand, and if you do, gain 1000 LP. You can only use this
>   effect of "Juragedo" once per turn. During either player's turn: You
>   can Tribute this card, then target 1 face-up monster you control; it
>   gains 1000 ATK until the end of the next turn.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No Juragedo does not *always* cause a replay. A replay only occurs if the number of monsters on the field changes while an attack is being declared, but before the damage step. Therefore Juragedo *can* cause a replay, but does not always cause one. If Juragedo is summoned as soon as the Battle Phase starts, then a replay will not occur, but if it is summoned immediately after an attack, then a replay will occur.

Answer (score -2):

yes it does. When the total number on monster changes on field then replay will always come.

Comment: Hi giga, welcome to stackexchange! Here we try to steer toward high-quality answers that are definitely true, often supported by reference links to a source of truth. I think you could improve your answer by providing a relevant quote from the rules, and a link thereto.

Comment: The Battle Step starts as an open gamestate where the turn player has priority to activate fast effects like that of Juragedo, or declare attacks. Found this in wikia. http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Breakdown_of_the_Battle_Phase